# React controlled input not behaving correctly on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs

I'm trying to set some validation for an input field. It is working fine everywhere except on iOS.

Here's some example code but the are two points to consider:

- It must be a `type="text"` input because I need to allow the user to type
  special characters like - and /
- I made some regex to handle the input validation but for the sake of
  simplicity I'm omitting it from the snippet.

https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-morning-gjjsq

The original code is from a React project with Redux so I reproduced the same logic with both state management from React and from Redux to make clear the problem is not coming from neither of them. In the example I set the if-else conditional to allow any value less or equal to 20 to be displayed in the input fields and, as I said, it works OK. Nothing fancy, it's just to demonstrate that when the value is greater than 20, or when is not even a numeric value, the input field won't get updated. But whatever the reason, for iOS when, **specifically**,  the *dash* (or *minus*) character is inserted in the input field the other characters get erased. Try typing 2- or 20- and the characters will disappear. If I try to type other character like / or ?, whatever, the values are not erased though. The desired behavior is to keep the value untouched (i.e. 2 or 20), not delete it.

The problem doesn't happen on Windows and on Android; it's only on iOS no matter the browser (not sure if it happens on Mac too). I tried `return false`, `e.preventDefault()`, `e.stopPropagation()`, `e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation()`. None of these worked.

Does anybody could help me with this? Again, the code I provided is just an example based on the original code which I can't reproduce here. I can clarify better if needed.